# In android can you load resources outside the ui thread

Tags: android

I have what is hopefully a simple question. I want to know if you can safely load resources from a non-ui thread. I'm talking about things in the "res" folder. I just can't find any documentation that definitively answers this question. There are a lot of mentions in the SDK related to what is not allowed on the UI Thread. I never saw anything that mentioned loading resources in this way.

For example can I call this code from a background thread?
    `Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_resource);`

Does it help if I remove the context.getResources() part and only do:
    `Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.icon_resource);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes** you can!

But it strongly depends on how the API's handle such calls. For example. if an API expects a context, then you may have to provide it the right one by saving your UI context and passing it on to the background thread.

However, when it comes to setting UI components, you will have to return to the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks. My intent is to read the resources on the background thread and use them only on the background thread.